# How to create a custom id in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a custom id in MongoDB.

Example- suppose I have a user document and in which the custom id should contain, first two letters of country code then after that two letters of state code then a random unique number.

Example: suppose the user is from India and the state is delhi so the id should look like this - INDL123

I am using NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property in your Schema named `CustomID` or whatever you want to name it and make it of type `string`, then you can use the function below to Generate the CustomID based on `country,city` passed.

This is just a quick example and can be improved a lot

```js
let country = 'India'
let city = 'Delhi'


function CreateCustomID(country, city) {
  return `${country.slice(0, 2).toUpperCase()}${city.slice(0,2).toUpperCase()}${Math.floor(Math.random()*(999-100+1)+100)}`
}


console.log(CreateCustomID(country, city))
```

Comment: But how can I get the user's country code and state code from it's coordinates. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: For that u need to google maps `geocoding API` which intakes coordinates and gives u the address, then get whatever information u need